# Jquery: How to show bootstrap tooltip

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

In my case, tooltip is coming when user place mouse on input control but I want to trigger tooltip. Means when validation will fail, then tooltip will be display below input control.

this is the code i am using to show tooltip. just tell me what to edit in this code.

```
var options = { html: true, placement: 'bottom', title: '<div class="tooltip-alert alert-danger" data-placement="bottom">' + message + '</div>' };
        $(inputElement).addClass('validation-error');
        inputElement.tooltip("destroy")
            .addClass("error")
            .tooltip(options);
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use this way:

```
$(element).tooltip("show");
```

So, when the validation error occurs, you need to use:

```
inputElement.tooltip("show");
```

Comment: @Thomas You have already initialized the options with `.tooltip(options);` before showing. So it has the options set. `:)`

Comment: @Thomas Can you show me a working fiddle using http://jsbin.com please? It would be easy for me. Make sure it is working before you send me. `:D`

Comment: thanks i understand but i notice when tooltip is showing and if i move mouse cursor on that input then tooltip is going....any work around exist?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, there is. Give me a moment.

Comment: i want tootip should not go. when validation success then it should go......what to do?

Comment: @Thomas **Provide a http://jsbin.com Fiddle**, which will make both of our work simpler.

Comment: can u tell me how to hide all open tooltip if i click on another button.

Comment: @Thomas Use this: `$(".tooltip").tooltip("hide");` hides all the open tooltips.

Answer (score 3):

After going through the comments, I feel you need a static tooltip to be displayed when there is an error.

Bootstrap tooltip `trigger=manual` is what you require.

Here is the fiddle for you : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/se2jz3vk/)

**Edit**
Added Hide button to hide tooltip.

[Fiddle# 2](https://jsfiddle.net/se2jz3vk/2/)

Hope this helps.

-Help :)

Comment: in your fiddle there should be another button which would close tooltips when clicked. in my case tooltips is generated dynamically in each table cell.

Comment: thanks for your code. when so many tooltips is opened then how could i close all. suppose tooltip related html is there in my each td and now i want to iterate table and extract one by one tooltip and hide it......how it will be possible?

Comment: just have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854273/jquery-how-hide-or-close-all-open-bootstarp-tooltip