# Jquery: How hide or close all open bootstrap tooltip

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This way I am showing bootstrap tooltip from my validation function.

```
var options = { html: true, placement: 'bottom', title: '<div class="tooltip-alert alert-danger" data-placement="bottom">' + message + '</div>' };
        $(inputElement).addClass('validation-error');
        inputElement.tooltip("destroy")
            .addClass("error")
            .tooltip(options);
inputElement.tooltip("show");
```

so when many tooltips is open and if i click on another button then tooltips are still open which is not good. so tell me how to hide or close all open bootstarp tooltips when user click on another button?

Answer (score 48):

When you have 100s of tooltips open, I believe you have given `.tooltip` class for everything. So, you can use this shorthand to close all the tooltips:

```
$(".tooltip").tooltip("hide");
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"], .tooltip').tooltip();
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"], .tooltip').tooltip("show");
  $("button").click(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"], .tooltip').tooltip("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
body {padding: 50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
<br /><br />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>

<br />
<br /><br /><br />
<button>Hide All</button>
```

Comment: sorry did not work. this is my tooltip html `<div class="tooltip fade bottom in" style="top: 231.5px; left: 212.592px; display: block;" data-original-title="" title=""><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"><div data-placement="bottom" class="tooltip-alert alert-danger">First name is required</div></div></div>`

Comment: i guess i need to iterate table and extract each tooltip from there and then hide.........what u say?

Comment: @Thomas What's preventing you to create a demo or snippet? Make it easy for both of us na? Did my example code work or not?

Comment: @Thomas I agree man. I see you are a good dev. Having a same ground for working will help both of us.

Comment: This is very useful for android `WebView` .. the `tooltip` sticks onscreen +1

Comment: @hexagod Thanks! 

Comment: This was the only thing that works for me `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"], .tooltip').tooltip("hide");`

Comment: @sebasira Thanks for sharing. In that case, those elements do not have the `tooltip` class then. Just the `data-toggle` attribute. 

Comment: Please excuse me, I maybe did not express well. What I meant was that of all other solutions I've tried yours was the only that really works! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

My sollution is

```
$(".ui-tooltip").css('display','none');
```

Answer (score 1):

i have done the job this way....just iterate in table.

```
function HideToolTips() {
    $('#StudentGrid tbody > tr').each(function (i, row) {
            $(this).find("input[id*='FirstName']").tooltip('hide');
            $(this).find("input[id*='LastName']").tooltip('hide');
            $(this).find("select[id*='cboState'] :selected").tooltip('hide');
            $(this).find("select[id*='cboCity'] :selected").tooltip('hide');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do this manually when my tooltips were not closing after a button click. I found this method helpful.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33585981/6151839)

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    trigger : 'hover'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help close tooltip at any button, any id

```
$(document).on("click","button",function(){$(this).trigger("blur")})
$(document).on("mouseup","button",function(){$(this).trigger("blur")})
$(document).on("mousedown","button",function(){$(this).trigger("blur")})
```

Tooltip will close button's tooltip on button click